# Atoi Function gives me random numbers

Tags: c

Hello i have a function called

```
int SearchKey(char key[]).
```

The key im giving is a string like this  2014-02-13T23:50:00

In the function i keep only the numbers which means my string becomes like this : 20140213235000

Until this part everything is working perfect.

After i call the atoi function

```
 NewResult=atoi(result);
```

my NewResult contains random numbers(NewResult is int),but when i had the whole proccess in the main i had zero problems.

Thanks everyone i made it by using the function strtoll.

Comment: 20140213235000 is too big for an `int`.

Comment: When i had the same thing in the main it was working perfect.Should i try with strtoll?

Comment: Try `long long atoll(const char *str);` ... but `strtoll` gives better checking.

Comment: `in the main it was working perfect` Code speaks louder than words. Post the full code and someone will figure it out.

Comment: "same thing in the main it was working perfect." --> Code optimized out the `atoi()` call.  With out of range the the result are UB.  Post a [mcve]

Comment: Joe, Tip: rather than only the opinion "contains random numbers" post the number seen.  It is more informative and often a clue to the solution.  Example: was it 1,111,584,056?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [atoi()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) *[emphasis added]*:

> int       atoi( const char *str );
>
> Return value
>
> Integer value corresponding to the contents of str on success. **If the converted value falls out of range of corresponding return type, the return value is undefined**. If no conversion can be performed, ​0​ is returned.

Instead, you should use [strtol()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) family functions, `strtoll()` in particular to convert such a big value. They also provide better error handling compare to `atoi()` family functions.

Comment: Commnet cleaner coming through - beep beep